# How to get wallet id of an order?

Tags: java-sdk

I want to block some dumpers of my coin. Is there any Java code which I can use to get the wallet id of the low offers?
For example if someone is buying less then 0.1 I want to get that offer and the wallet which submitted that offer.
How can I do that using the Java SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone answered a similar question here regarding how to get all the holders of an asset: [List all asset holder](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/724/list-all-asset-holder)

If you know all your asset holders, you could theoretically stream all orders made by these accounts and then act upon the accounts that fit your criteria of a coin dumper -- as an asset creator you can:

- [Control Asset Holders](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html#controlling-asset-holders)
- [Revoke Access](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html#revoking-access)